# Add remove class Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created this code in Jquery.

And it is working fine but I am trying  to accomplish this: I DON'T want to add a CLASS right away  (on document load) like in this example **INSTEAD** I would try to accomplish the following:

ON FIRST click select **FIRST li tag** and **THEN** add Class "active". I want to achieve the same functionality like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVLE6/) . (Only difference is that I DON'T want **first li** tag to have CLASS right away , but to add a CLASS on button click.) Can someone help me out? Thank you!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $("button").click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {
       if($('ul li.active').length==0)
           $('ul li:first-child').addClass('active');
       else
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')

   });
});
```

try here http://jsfiddle.net/KVLE6/2/

In that case you need to check if there is any item with active class. If there is at least one, then remove to it and add it to next. If there is none, then add it to first. Let me know if that's what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $active= $('.active');  
    if( !$active.length){
        $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
    }else{
        $active.removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $("button").click(function() {
        if($('li.active').length > 0) {

            $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
        }else{
            console.log($('ul li:first'));
            $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KVLE6/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i=0
$("button").click(function() {

    if(i > $("ul > li").length)
    {
       i=0;     
    }
    $("ul > li").siblings().removeClass('active');            
    $("ul > li:eq("+i+")").removeClass('active').addClass('active');
    i++;
});
});
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/KVLE6/25/